# jquery scroll to section is broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this bit of functionality that somewhere is broken and I can't catch the error. Clicking section one, doesn't go to section one. I might have missed something on the `redrawDotNav`. Would be nice if someone could have a look for me and get it woking:-) 
Thanks,

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  redrawDotNav();
});

$('a.sec01').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000, function() {});
  return false;
});
$('a.sec01').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#sec02').offset().top
  }, 1000, function() {});
  return false;
});
$('a.sec03').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#sec03').offset().top
  }, 1000, function() {});
  return false;
});
$('a.sec04').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#sec04').offset().top
  }, 1000, function() {});
  return false;
});

function redrawDotNav() {
  var section1Top = 0;
  var section2Top = $('#sec02').offset().top - (($('#sec03').offset().top - $('#sec02').offset().top) / 2);
  var section3Top = $('#sec03').offset().top - (($('#sec04').offset().top - $('#sec03').offset().top) / 2);
  var section4Top = $('#sec04').offset().top - (($(document).height() - $('#sec04').offset().top) / 2);

  $('.sticky-indicators a').removeClass('active');


  if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section1Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section2Top) {
    $('.sticky-indicators a.sec01').addClass('active');

  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section2Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section3Top) {
    $('.sticky-indicators a.sec02').addClass('active');

  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section3Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section4Top) {
    $('.sticky-indicators a.sec03').addClass('active');


  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section4Top) {
    $('.sticky-indicators a.sec04').addClass('active');
  }

}
```

```css
img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.sticky-indicators {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  background: white;
  width:200px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="sticky-indicators">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#sec01" class="sec01">Section 01</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#sec02" class="sec02">Section 02</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#sec03" class="sec03">Section 03</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#sec04" class="sec04">Section 04</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="col xs-col-12 xs-ralative">

  <div id="sec01" class="col xs-col-12">
    <img class="col xs-col-12" src="../styles/images/pdp-1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="sec02" class="col xs-col-12">
    <img class="col xs-col-12" src="../styles/images/5.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="sec03" class="col xs-col-12">
    <img class="col xs-col-12" src="../styles/images/4.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="sec04" class="col xs-col-12 ">
    <img class="col xs-col-12" src="../styles/images/7.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay try this code. You just duplicate your onclick selector `$('a.sec02')` you forgot this class

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  redrawDotNav();
});

$('a.sec01').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000, function() {});
  return false;
});
$('a.sec02').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#sec02').offset().top
  }, 1000, function() {});
  return false;
});
$('a.sec03').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#sec03').offset().top
  }, 1000, function() {});
  return false;
});
$('a.sec04').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#sec04').offset().top
  }, 1000, function() {});
  return false;
});

function redrawDotNav() {
  var section1Top = 0;
  var section2Top = $('#sec02').offset().top - (($('#sec03').offset().top - $('#sec02').offset().top) / 2);
  var section3Top = $('#sec03').offset().top - (($('#sec04').offset().top - $('#sec03').offset().top) / 2);
  var section4Top = $('#sec04').offset().top - (($(document).height() - $('#sec04').offset().top) / 2);

  $('.sticky-indicators a').removeClass('active');


  if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section1Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section2Top) {
    $('.sticky-indicators a.sec01').addClass('active');

  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section2Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section3Top) {
    $('.sticky-indicators a.sec02').addClass('active');

  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section3Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section4Top) {
    $('.sticky-indicators a.sec03').addClass('active');


  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section4Top) {
    $('.sticky-indicators a.sec04').addClass('active');
  }

}
```

```css
img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.sticky-indicators {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  background: white;
  width:200px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="sticky-indicators">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#sec01" class="sec01">Section 01</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#sec02" class="sec02">Section 02</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#sec03" class="sec03">Section 03</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#sec04" class="sec04">Section 04</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="col xs-col-12 xs-ralative">

  <div id="sec01" class="col xs-col-12">
    <img class="col xs-col-12" src="../styles/images/pdp-1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="sec02" class="col xs-col-12">
    <img class="col xs-col-12" src="../styles/images/5.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="sec03" class="col xs-col-12">
    <img class="col xs-col-12" src="../styles/images/4.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="sec04" class="col xs-col-12 ">
    <img class="col xs-col-12" src="../styles/images/7.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy. really appreciated.